# Chrome duplicate tabs: extension that is not preventing, but actually finds them on demand

Tags: chrome

There are plenty of extensions that preventing the opening of new duplicated tabs. But I don't need them. When I open duplicate tab, I do it for a reason (90% of times).

I need an extension that actually find opened duplicate tabs in all Chrome windows and shows me a list of them so I can choose, which to close. Ok, I'm even agree extension will be closing them automatically after I press the button. And ok if it will not have list. But it must find duplicates in all windows and not prevent opening, but rather close on demand.

There is one extension I've found, but it (clams that it) searches tabs in one window, which is useless to me.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-dupectomy/nkkedbpcfdogedipgdhgeknjdphaplbk?hl=en

Comment: I agree [tag:tab] *might* need to be made soon - but we'll see - but you really don't need any other tags because 'chrome' means 'chrome extension' and a 'duplicate' tag would be useless as hardly anyone would use it!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ i don't think `duplicate` would be useless. i see many applications, actually

Answer (score 2):

You need [One Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall?hl=en) extension that will group all the open tabs into one single tab where you can choose and close them.

[Hattip](http://www.gtricks.com/chrome/prevent-duplicate-tabs-of-same-url/)

Comment: Can you include key points from your "Hattip" link?  Thanks!

Comment: lol. one tab extension is actually what i'm referring to when asking "extension that is not preventing, but actually finds them on demand". now read the title of article u linked (to double the effect): "Prevent Chrome from Opening Duplicate Tabs". wtf really.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Duplicate Tabs Closer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tabs-closer/gnmdbogfankgjepgglmmfmbnimcmcjle) extension for Chrome (there is a version for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate-tabs-closer/) as well), which allows you to specify the action on duplicate tab detected. You can also list current duplicate tabs and close them manually. It supports the scope of active or all windows.